# How to reduce accidentally pressing the right-button on a trackball?

Tags: technology, comfort, efficiency, moving, work

Instead of a computer mouse, I use a trackball for a pointing device.  I find that it is much healthier for my wrist, elbow, and shoulder.

The only downside I experience is that I often accidentally click the right-button.  This happens because I have fairly large and heavy hands, and the trackball I use is ergonomically designed to keep the wrist at an angle (instead of flat).

What clever techniques will reduce the number of erroneous right-clicks that I perform?

---

Edit: Here is a video review of the trackball.  At about 1:40, you can see how the reviewer's hand is positioned and how it could accidentally press the right-button with just a little pressure.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TGrNG_6LurI

Also, here are two static images at different angles:

[image: Logitech 570 Wireless Trackball Top Image]
[image: Logitech 570 Wireless Trackball Angle Image]

Comment: Can you show us a picture of said trackball and your hand resting on it?

Comment: @CaiusJard Better than just a picture, I've added a video. :)

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how often you right-click, I would first attempt to limit the mouse button from being pressed at all by using something like a flat toothpick as a shim to hold that button position open.

On the occasion where a right-click is required, press the equivalent key on the keyboard with your free hand.

To enable the keyboard right-click key for Windows 10,

Step 1: Navigate to Settings app > System > Tablet mode.
Step 2: In When I sign in drop-down box, select Use desktop mode. ...

You can also restart to turn off the tablet mode.
You should now be able to right-click on the desktop.

To right-click on a MAC keyboard, Ctrl (Control)-click has the desired effect.

Comment: Thank you Stan.  Unfortunately, I need to right-click hundreds of times per day.